# Quantum Optics: entropy doesn't change!

Tags: quantum-mechanics, entropy, quantum-optics

I'm reading a paper and without any justification, the author said:

*Consider a single-mode cavity field initially prepared in a coherent state $|\alpha_0 \rangle$. It leaks out of the cavity through the front mirror, until at long times the cavity-field state becomes the vacuum $|0 \rangle$.*

*The point is that the state has changed and so has its mean energy E(t) but not its purity or **entropy**.*

Why entropy doesn't change?

At the first, I thought that it's because we already know the initial state and the final state and because of entropy is related to the information you have about the system, this means that entropy is zero. But I think I am wrong because this argument fails and is too subjective.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is because you know the initial and the final state, you can calculate their entropies and they are both zero. They are zero because the (von-Neumann) entropy of any pure state is zero.

Remember that for $\rho = \sum_k p_k |\psi_k\rangle\langle\psi_k|$ (where $\langle\psi_k|\psi_\ell\rangle = \delta_{k\ell}$) the entropy is defined as
$$ S(\rho) = -k_B \sum_k p_k \ln p_k . $$
In other words, the entropy is zero since you know for certain in which (pure) state your system is.